# Equivalent command matlab<>opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv

Does anyone knows what is the equivalent command for logical (matlab) for opencv? I saw that the bit depth for a logical image(1 channel) is equal to '1'. For a normal 1 channel image, we can set it to 8U or 32F (meaning, the bit depth is 8, 32). Am I right? The reason I'm asking because when I tried thinning using matlab, image(logical) and image(uint8 @ im2double) give different results.

Comment: CV_8UC1 means 8-bit single-channel matrix.

Comment: Ya. 8 bit with single channel. But when I use I_logic = logical(I);~matlab it return bit depth of 1.

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB, `logical` type has a size of 1 **byte**. Try the following:

```
>> x = true
x =
     1

>> whos x
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class      Attributes

  x         1x1                 1  logical
```

So the equivalent to a logical image in OpenCV would be `8U` image with a single-channel